# Prove that $f$ is bounded using halving technique

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Question :

Assume that $f$ is a function defined on $[a,b]$ and $f$ is locally bounded on each point of $[a,b]$.
Prove that $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ **using halving technique. ( Sometimes called bisection method )**

My try :

I assumed that $f$ is not bounded on $[a,b]$.

I need to prove that there exists a nested sequence of intervals $\{[a_n,b_n]\}$ such that for each $n$ , $f$ is not bounded on $[a_n,b_n]$.

If i do that , Then according to nested intervals' theorem, I can conclude that since length of intervals are getting closer and closer to $0$, then intersection of all intervals is just $1$ point.

Call this one point $p$. With this method, We showed that there is no neighbourhood of $p$ such that values near to $p$ are bounded on that neighbourhood. That's a contradiction with $f$ being locally bounded on each point of $[a,b]$, including $p$. So, we're done.

The thing i'm stuck on is how to prove this sequence of nested intervals exist.  Please don't mention other ways to prove the theorem. Just show me how to complete my proof.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$. If $f$ is not bounded on $[a,b]$ then either it's not bounded on $[a,c]$ or it's not bounded on $[c,b]$. Whichever one, let that be $[a_1,b_1]$. Continue bisecting the interval and always choose the half on which $f$ is not bounded (it could be both, but in any case, there is a half on which $f$ is not bounded).

Comment: @kccu how can u be sure that its a closed interval ? i mean not $[a,c)$ for example ?

Comment: If $f$ is unbounded on $[a,c)$ then surely it is also unbounded on $[a,c]$. Another way to see it is this: if $f$ were bounded on both $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$, it would have to be bounded on all of $[a,b]$.